# Android: Record Audio using MediaRecorder gives runtimeException during whatsapp audio call

Tags: android, audio-recording, whatsapp, mediarecorder

I am trying to record whatsapp audio calls in my application. My code work fine sim calls or simple recording but when start call on whatsapp or facebook messenger and start recording during social networks calls i get runtimeExceptin and MediaRecorder start failed.

I use this simple code.

```
private void startRecording() {

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/Asimkhanmak.3gp";

    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
   // mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
   // mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);



    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pre "+ e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        mRecorder.start();

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start "+ e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

I also tried Mic as AudioSource but it didn't worked.

Comment: did you fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try run this at "**Activity extends Service**" instead of Normal Activity.

And your "try catch", why do it in different try catch? Just put it together instead. Don't waste the line of code.